# Intent.toUri(0): in Reverse Order

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

We can simply convert `Intent` objects to `Uri` objects:

```java
Intent intent = ...;
Uri uri = intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);  // The value of flag is not important for me.
```

How can do it in reverse order?

---

**My knowledge**:

There is  a static method that gets `String` as it's parameter. (Of course, it has been deprecated.)

```java
Intent.getIntent(String uri);
```

And also two constructors that accept `Uri`, but those also take other parameters that I don't know their values:

```java
1) Intent(String action, Uri uri);
2) Intent(String action, Uri uri, Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

I only have a `uri` and the value of `flags` parameter that passed to `toUri(int flags)`.

---

**Additional information**:

Actually, I have a `WebResourceRequest` object that comes from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` (of `WebViewClient` class).

I won't have any problem when don't pay attention to **deprecation**. Because the below way works actually fine:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Intent intent = Intent.getIntent(url);
    ...
}
```

But both `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, String)` and `Intent.getIntent(String)` have been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `parseUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#parseUri(java.lang.String,%20int)). Quoting the documentation:

> Create an intent from a URI. This URI may encode the action, category, and other intent fields, if it was returned by toUri(int). If the Intent was not generate by toUri(), its data will be the entire URI and its action will be ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: You mean `Intent.parseUri(request.getUrl().toString(), flags)`? I will test it soon and report the result.